# Re-assign old slug from old model to new model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

- I'm using FriendlyId to handle my slugs and so far it has been good.
- I have created a model with `{name: "first name"}` and my slug is
  auto-generate using `slug_candidates`.

Here's part of the code

```
ruby
...
friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => [:scoped, :history], :scope => :company
...
private
def slug_candidates
  [:slug, [:name]]
end
```

- I can update the model with a new slug and everything work fine. I
  can also use the old slug to find the model and it works fine because
  of the `history` module from FriendlyId

create works

```
ruby
model_a = {name: "Model A", slug: "model-a"}
```

update also works

```
ruby
model_a = {name: "Model A", slug: "model-b"}


ruby
model_a = {name: "Model A", slug: "model-c"} # just changed the name of the slug
```

find also works with history

```
ruby
GET api/v1/models/model_a  returns model_a
GET api/v1/models/model_b  returns model_a
GET api/v1/models/model_c  returns model_a
```

I want to be able to do the following

Create a new model with the old (history) slug.

```
 ruby
    POST api/v1/models {:name => "New Model", :slug => "model-b"} # using the old history for model_a
```

#### Update an existing model with an old slug as well

```
ruby
PUT api/v1/models/models-c {:name => "New Model", :slug => "model-b"}
```

However, there is a conflict due to the uniqueness of the slug for the model and my implementation does not work.

I've tried the following

```
before_save -> { delete_old_slug_if_conflicts self.slug }  
  private
  def delete_old_slug_if_conflicts (slug)
    # get the id of the slug from the friendly_id_lug table
    id = FriendlyId::Slug.where(slug: slug, sluggable_type: 'Model')[0].sluggable_id
    # get an array of all the slugs for that model
    slugs = FriendlyId::Slug.where(sluggable_id: id, sluggable_type: 'Model').order("created_at asc")
    # if the count is more than 1, then the first one is the old history and is deleted,
    if slugs.count > 1
      id_to_del = slugs.first["id"].to_i
      return FriendlyId::Slug.destroy(id_to_del) # remove the slug record to allow for saving
    end
    nil
  end
```

Is there a better way to achieve this re-assignment or is there something I'm missing?
By the way, I'm not an expert in rails and I'm using `Rails 4.2.5.1`